# Pointers in structures

Tags: c++, c

First to tell you my issue:

I have written a program that based on this struct..

```
typedef struct{ 
    char firstname [40];    
    char lastname [40]; 
    char address [100]; 
    char phone[11];
}contact;
```

will ask the user for input and then write it to a file. Except that when I do write to the file, it writes i.e for first name, the rest of the 40 characters and so everything is spaced out..

A colleague of mine suggest creating a structure of pointers but I'm unfamiliar with this concept completely. I have this so far in replacement of the above structure:

```
typedef struct{ 
    char* firstname;    
    char lastname [40]; 
    char address [100]; 
    char phone[11];
}contact;
```

in which case I'm only working on first name right now. I have seen examples that create a separate array

```
char comm[100];

fgets(entry.firstname, 40, stdin);
entry.firstname = new char[strlen(comm)];
```

or something to this affect but this is giving me fits. What I want is to have the person enter an entry in and the size of the field grow and shrink to what is entered by the user. Any fixes would be appreciated!

Sorry for leaving this out :/ :

```
pFile = fopen("C:\\contacts.txt", "r+");

if(!pFile){
    puts("File could not be open.");
    return 1;
    }

fwrite(&entry,1,sizeof(entry),pFile);
```

Comment: How are you writing this to a file? If you writing this out as a text file a properly terminated string should not print the extra characters.

Comment: editted above guys. sorry about that

Comment: `new char[strlen(comm)];` and the `c` tag are mutually exclusive...

Comment: If you are writing the structure with something like write( fd, data, sizeof *data ), then changing the value to a pointer will be totally unhelpful, as you will be writing a memory location to the file and that memory will be meaningless outside of the process that writes it.  If you write the data memberwise, it will not matter if the structure member is a pointer or an array.

Comment: Your structure is fine, but your saving/loading approach is where I would tackle this issue. Instead of saving the struct byte for byte, save each member individually. Save the contents of each string, but just up to the zero terminator. Read it back in the same manner, just up to the zero terminator. This will save you lots of grief when you come to change the layout of the struct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How do you do that with my code? If you don't mind showing me in an answer.

Comment: Well, since you are using C++ I would first of all switch to using `string`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with string. Can this be solved without adding more material? I'm trying to do this "this" way and then revise it after with more efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: C++ is a huge bulk of material for you. Anyway, `std::string` is much easier to use for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're just dumping the entire `contact` structure to a file.  What you want to do instead is write out only the characters the user entered.  Fortunately, this is easy.  To get started, let's just print out the first name:

```
fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", entry.firstname);
```

If you're using C++, you should use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Your struct can now look like

```
typedef struct{ 
    std::string firstname;    
    std::string lastname; 
    std::string address; 
    std::string phone;
}contact;
```

And you can write to a file using fstream

```
std::ofstream outfile("C:\\contacts.txt");
outfile << contact.firstname << std::endl
        << contact.lastname << std::endl
        << contact.address << std::endl
        << contact.phone << std::endl;
outfile.close();
```

Comment: Does your code not include the whole firstname array? i.e. 40 bytes?

Comment: @Questioneer Since it's using `fprintf` it will stop writing once it hits the first `\0` character.

Comment: I see. What kind of functionality do I need to add if I want to do this several times for several entries?

Comment: @Questioneer The important part is the line starting with `outfile << contact.firstname << std::endl //...`.  Just repeat this whole line for each contact you wish to write to the file.  When you're done, do `outfile.close()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `new` then you are using C++, not C. If so, you should use `std::string` to store strings. That should be far easier than pointers or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, I don't think there is a `new` in C. Second, if `entry` is a pointer, you have to get `firstname` like so:

```
entry->firstname;
```

If you wanted to set the pointer to a new character array, you could:

```
char comm[100];
entry->firstname = &comm;
```

or something similar.